# What happened to Kaiki in Monogatari Series?

Tags: monogatari-series

We saw at the end of Monogatari Second Season that

> Kaiki is apparently killed by one of the boys (or girls?, I do not remember very well) he scammed.

If I followed the storyline correctly, this happens just after the events that involved Nadeko, but before the graduation of Araragi and Senjōgahara.

Then, on Hanamonogatari, which is after the graduation of Araragi and Senjōgahara,

> Kaiki is still alive and kicking, and without any evidence of the beating that he received.

Am I missing something in the storyline?

> Because he should be dead by the beating that he received. Why he is not?

Comment: All we know is that he is not dead. How he survived is not really mentioned in the anime, though.

Comment: My personal theory is that the attack did not happen as we were shown, and Kaiki, a self-proclaimed unreliable narrator, lied to us. After all, Kaiki narrates Koimonogatari, and he starts the novel version by telling us that he's a liar and we shouldn't believe anything he says. Then at the end he narrates his own death, but later, more reliable narrators tell us he's alive. This is probably explained further in the third season novels, though.

Comment: That is an excellent theory! The fact that the author might have integrated us into one of Kaiki lies sounds awesome!

Comment: just wanna highlight that the anime series is not in chronological order as the light novels https://www.reddit.com/r/araragi/comments/1mezh0/the_orders_to_monogatari/

Answer (score 2):

To sum it up pretty simply,

> Kaiki lived from his attack. How he lived, and what he's been up to after that point, we don't really know.

Chronologically, Hanamonogatari is the last story in the entire Monogatari series. So, what we see there is about all we get, unfortunately.

Edit (7 April 2016): It seems there is now a "fourth season" of Monogatari novels. I don't personally know yet where these novels fall chronologically, but it's possible that more information about what happened to Kaiki could be contained in these novels.